# What are the expansions of TUN and TAP acronyms?

Tags: vpn, documentation

Many VPN software use the TUN or TAP kernel driver to create a virtual network interface (mainly for Linux and FreeBSD systems). I know [how they work and the differences](https://serverfault.com/questions/21157/should-i-use-tap-or-tun-for-openvpn), this is purely a lexicographic question.

Just out of curiosity, what actually mean TUN and TAP? Are they acronyms? I can't find much on internet, someone says TUN is a shorthand for tunnel, but I can't find any confirmation of this. Neither [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TUN/TAP) nor the [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/tuntap.txt) provide the expansion for the acronyms. Not even the [original sourceforge website](http://vtun.sourceforge.net/tun/).

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/tuntap.html

Comment: @Jason Croyle ? It doesn't seem to contain the answer

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TUN/TAP _"TUN, namely network TUNnel"_, _"TAP, namely network TAP"_

Answer (score 0):

TUN stands for [Tunneling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunneling_protocol)

TAP stands for [Network tap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_tap)